# SQL query to fetch monthly sales data for each category for items sold at discounted rate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I intend to prepare a SQL query to **perform monthly sales for each categories at discounted rate**.

This is the sample table structure I have in **SQL Server** (showing only the required columns)

**Items Table:**

| ItemID | SubCategoryID | PurchaseDate | PurchaseType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 11 | 01-22-2021 | Discounted |
| 3456 | 12 | 01-22-2021 | Full |
| 5678 | 13 | 02-10-2021 | Discounted |
| 6788 | 12 | 01-01-2021 | Discounted |

**SubCategory Table**

| SubCategoryID | SubCategoryName |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Mobile |
| 12 | Laptop |
| 13 | Tshirt |
| 14 | Plant |

**Category Table**

| CategoryID | CategoryName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Electronics |
| 2 | Apparels |
| 3 | Decoration |

**CategoryMapping Table**

| CategoryID | SubCategoryID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 14 |

As of now I've prepared a SQL query to perform **sales per category at discounted rate** as follows:

```
select
CategoryName,
Count(*) as 'Count of Total Items',
count(case when PurchaseType = 'Discounted' then 1 else null end)  as 'Count of Discounted Items'
from
 (select
i.ItemID,
i.PurchaseDate,
i.PurchaseType AS PurchaseType,
c.CategoryName AS CategoryName
from 
Items i
LEFT Join SubCategory sc with(nolock) on sc.SubCategoryID = i.SubCategoryID
LEFT Join CategoryMapping cm with(nolock) on cm.SubCategoryID  = i.SubCategoryID
LEFT Join Category c with(nolock) on c.CategoryID = cm.CategoryID     

where i.PurchaseDate > '01/01/2021' and i.PurchaseDate < '12/31/2021'
)as Data
group by CategoryName
```

This query works fine.

Now I need to modify this query further to get the **monthly sales** for each **CategoryNames.**

So in this case grouping would be required using **PurchaseDate** column but I'm not able to figure out to tweak the above query in the optimal way.

The current SQL above does a calculation based on Category grouping between the below given date range (which will always be limited to a given single year and not span across another year)
i.PurchaseDate > '01/01/2021' and i.PurchaseDate < '12/31/2021'

Now the requirement is to further breakdown sales for each Category grouping based on the Purchase Date's month.

Ultimately the result must look something as follows:

| CategoryName | Month | Count if Total Items | Count of Discounted Items | Count of Discounted Items Per Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Electronics | Jan | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| Apparels | Feb | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Decoration | March | 0 | 0 | 0 |

How can I fetch monthly sales data by further tweaking my existing query

Comment: There is no transaction for the month march in your given data set. But you show with zero value. Kindly explain

Comment: Correct. Since there's no transaction it should show up 0.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And i guess you plan on never having any sales on the last day of the year?

Comment: First step is to aggregate into monthly values. How do you think you should to that? Grouping by year and month somehow, surely? Try that and get it working as a first step. Note that you likely do need to sort your resultset - i suggest you think about and implement that as well.

Comment: I'm lost.  You have zero values in March for Decoration.  Where are the rows for the other categories?  They also have no transactions.

Answer (score 0):

To get rows with zero for months where there are no results, use a calendar table, and left join all the other results to it.

Normally one would use a proper calendar table, but in this instance, there are always exactly 12 months, so you can just use a virtual `VALUES` table

```sql
SELECT
    CategoryName,
    EOMONTH(MIN(i.PurchaseDate)) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) AS [Count of Total Items],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN PurchaseType = 'Discounted' THEN 1 END) AS [Count of Discounted Items Per Month],
    SUM(
      COUNT(CASE WHEN PurchaseType = 'Discounted' THEN 1 END)
      ) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CategoryID) AS [Total Count of Discounted Items]
FROM (VALUES
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
) AS v(Month)
LEFT JOIN Items i
    JOIN CategoryMapping cm on cm.SubCategoryID  = i.SubCategoryID
    JOIN Category c on c.CategoryID = cm.CategoryID
  ON MONTH(i.PurchaseDate) = v.Month
    AND i.PurchaseDate >= '20210101' and i.PurchaseDate < '20220101'
GROUP BY
  c.CategoryID,
  c.CategoryName;
```

You may want to consider `GROUPING SETS` instead of the `SUM` window function.

Notes:

- Never use `NOLOCK` unless you really know what you are doing, it can cause incorrect results
- Use inner joins rather than left joins, unless you'd like to include results with no match from the second table
- Use unambiguous date formats, such as `'20210101`
- Use half-open intervals for dates: an inclusive start and exclusive end date
- Use `[]` to quote column names, not `''`
- If possible, always group by a column that uniquely identifies a grouping